Unable to access ifcopenshell sub-modules from any parent level import
Using the ifcopenshell (0.8.0 at the time of writing) Python 3.11 package available from pypi: (source code on github), I'm not able to use it the way I'm used to use almost every other Python packages:
import ifcopenshell

ifcopenshell.api.project.create_file()

I'm facing this error:
AttributeError: module 'ifcopenshell' has no attribute 'api'

Same goes with whatever "sub-folder" inside this package, e.g.:
import ifcopenshell.api as api

api.project.create_file()
AttributeError: module 'ifcopenshell.api' has no attribute 'project'

I'm really used to having access of all sub-stuff  from a top-level import in almost all Python packages I'm using. Why this behavior in this particular package? How is this called (if it has a name)? And how would you fix it in the source code?
Currently, it's not a big issue as I can use it this way:
import ifcopenshell.api.project

ifcopenshell.api.project.create_file()
<ifcopenshell.file.file at 0x7da934029490>

but the code is getting long and tedious to write, and I'm forced to manually specify each and every sub-package/sub-sub-package/... imports.
